# vim shortcuts in webstorm

Tags: vim, sublimetext2, webstorm

There's a [vintage mode](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/vintage.html) in Sublime Text. Is there such a thing for WebStorm?
Tried to google, but didn't find anything so far.

Comment: Downvoters, please, comment. Is it a punishment for bad luck in google? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try IdeaVim plugin (Vim emulation ) available from the repository (Settings/Plugins, Browse repositories..., search for IdeaVim).